# Fork() and Execl() in C++, Execl() is failing

Tags: c++, string, character, exec, fork

I am trying to run execl() in C++, but it fails and I'm not sure why.

```
  string fileName = "test.txt";
  string computerName = "jssoile@palmetto.school.edu";
  pid_t pid;
  int    status;

  if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {     /* fork a child process           */
     printf("*** ERROR: forking child process failed\n");
     exit(1);
  }
  else if (pid == 0) {          /* for the child process:         */
     if (execl("scp", fileName.c_str(), computerName.c_str(), NULL) < 0) {     /* execute the command  */
        printf("*** ERROR: exec failed\n");
        exit(1);
     }
  }
  else {                                /* for the parent:      */
     while (wait(&status) != pid)       /* wait for completion  */
     ;
  }
```

When I run this, my execl() call fails and I print out

```
*** ERROR: exec failed
```

Comment: Your post does not contain a question; please edit your post.  Regardless, replace your `printf("*** ERROR: exec failed\n")` with `perror("scp")`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the `exec` variant that requires a full path as the first argument.

Replace:

```
execl( "scp", ... )
```

with either

```
execl("/usr/bin/scp", ...)
```

or

```
execlp("scp", ... )
```

Reference: http://linux.die.net/man/3/execl

Answer (score 0):

Your execl syntax is not correct.  You need to specify the complete path to scp (including scp) as the first argument, followed by your list of arguments.